# Remove Namespaces Prefix in Sandcastle

Tags: .net, namespaces, sandcastle

I have a large project with long namespaces, like

```
CompanyName.Product.Component.Class
```

Using Sandcastle to build the documentation for the namespaces, but those long namespaces really screw up the display of the contents pane in the final chm file.  How can I get it to display just `Component.Class` in at least the Treeview panel?

And/Or maybe have `CompanyName` as the root node that expands to `Product` which then expands to `Component`, expanding to all the namespaces under Component?